# Is there any way to build the library of the mail core, instead of dragging the project into my project directly

Tags: ios, mailcore

I want use Mail core to send/receive email in my iOS app, is there any way to just build the static lib for use, but not drag the source in my project?

Comment: why would this be better?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I built a static library using Carthage and then added that framework into my project. It's been working fine.